# How JsFiddle disallow document.write

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, document.write

How jsfiddle [ How can i .. ] break any code has `document.write();`
 in js textarea & doesnt excute that script inside result iframe .. is it posible with pure javascript

trying with :) but i know that's not good & so Naive

```
    var getjs = document.getElementById('js-textarea');
    getjs.replace(/document.write/g,''); 
   // or replace with innerHTML
   getjs.replace(/document.write/g,'myIFrame.body.innerHTML=');
  //working but it doesnt excute script
```

i hope to find suggestions for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may simply overwrite the function:

```js
document.write=function(){
      alert('document.write is not allowed');
    }
                                             
    document.write('this should be written');
```

Comment: thanx Dr , its so fine & working solution , but what about scripts `document.write('<script>alert("hello");<\/script>');`.

Comment: when `write` has been overwritten you also may not write `<script/>`'s

Comment: thanx Dr :) thats enough

Comment: example with an iframe(I guess something like that is your final goal ): http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/xkphvqtn/

Comment: yes, it works good , but why it doesnt read `onclick='func()'` for example `<textarea id='txi' onkeyup='gun()'>hello text area</textarea><button onclick='gun()'>alert</button>` with javascript function `function gun(){
alert(document.getElementById('txi').value);}`

Comment: browser show `<button onclick="">alert</button>` and the same with onkeyup

Comment: i'm sorry for disturbing , if you still here .. i found the problem its `doc.write()` is unstable with `window.onload` if my comment is not related  with my Q i'll open anew , sorry again

Comment: when you use `document.write` **after** a document has been loaded(that's the case in `window.onload`) you overwrite the entire document(all previous contents will be removed)